# (Pycharm mac os x) can't flush to file

Tags: python, macos, flush

I want to write to the file in real time(instead of waiting for the code to finish) by flushing, but it doesn't seem to change anything.
Here's the code:

```
 dataFile =open("json",'a+')

 def write(data):
        dataFile.write(data)
        dataFile.flush()
```

also `dataFile.close()` didn't change anything. Does anyone know what the problem is?

EDIT:
I managed to make it work by adding `os.fsync(dataFile.fileno())` right after `dataFile.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the standard Python library for JSON
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html

I think the use of open file inside the function by the global name is not correct.